# del Operator in Arbitrarily Nested List

Tags: python

I'm working with an instance of nltk.tree.ParentedTree, but I think the question is more general than that.

Basically, I have a list of arbitrarily deep nesting, and I want to delete part of the list (though I don't know how deeply nested that part is). I have a `search` function that finds an occurrence of an item in the list, which returns a tuple of `n` integers, where `n` is the depth of the element that was found.

For example, say I have `l = [[['cat', 'dog']], ['fish']]` When I call `search(l, 'dog')` it returns `(0, 0, 1)`. This is telling me that `l[0][0][1] == 'dog'`. If I knew that `'dog'` occurred at `(0, 0, 1)` ahead of time, I could delete it from the list just by doing `del l[0][0][1]`. But I don't know that ahead of time so I need to programmatically do the same kind of thing.

I can access the element `'dog'` in the list by doing

```
indices = search(l, 'dog')
for i in indices:
    l = l[i]
```

So now `l` is `'dog'`. But, I'm not sure how to get from there to deleting it from the list. I don't just want to set it to `None`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can loop over all but the last of the references and then use the last one to delete the item:

```
obj = l
for index in indices[:-1]:
    obj = obj[index]
del obj[indices[-1]]
```

By using all but the last index you resolved the reference to the *parent* of the referenced item, so now you can delete it with the last index.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
del reduce(lambda cur, ind: cur[ind], index_list[:-1], l)[index_list[-1]]
```

Which is really just a fancier way of doing exactly what @Martijn Pieters suggests in his answer.

Comment: `s/fancier/uglier and more convoluted/`. One liners and functional programming aren't always better.

Comment: I would argue ugly and convoluted is in the eye of the beholder, given that it represents nearly identical logic with quite similar statements, but I will grant that it is more arcane since it isn't just usage of basic syntax.